# ValueError at (url) seek of closed file in Django app

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to add an image processing library inside a webodm django app that takes input image path, output directory path. I do not want to save the input image inside the database so I was implementing the image processing on the fly. I end up getting: `ValueError at /plugins/diagnostic/ seek of closed file`

here is part of my view that handles the image processing:

```
        def vegetative_indices_view(request):
            print(cv2.__version__)
            if request.method == 'POST':
                form = VegetativeIndicesForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
                if form.is_valid():
                    uploaded_image = form.cleaned_data['input_image']
                    
                    # Read the uploaded image into memory
                    uploaded_image.seek(0)
                    image_data = uploaded_image.read()
                    uploaded_image.close()

                    # Create an in-memory file-like object for the image
                    in_memory_file = BytesIO(image_data)
                    in_memory_file.name = uploaded_image.name

                    # Normalize the uploaded image
                    normalized_image = normalize(Image.open(in_memory_file))

                    # Call the vegetative indices calculation logic
                    indexes = calculate_vegetative_indices(normalized_image)
                    return render(request, self.template_path('vegetative_indices_results.html'), {'indexes': indexes})
            else:
                form = VegetativeIndicesForm()
            return render(request, self.template_path("vegetative_indices.html"), {'form': form})
```

and in the terminal the error is printed like so:

```
webapp      |     return func(*args, **kwargs)
webapp      | ValueError: seek of closed file
```

What could be the issue here where the image file is prematurely closed?